# CSS footer will not sit at the bottom of viewport and other misc questions

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of teaching myself how to code html/css through various online tutorials and this excellent site.

I've coded this simple css layout just as a test.

A couple of things that I can't seem to workout:

1. How can I force the footer to stick to the bottom of the viewport when there isn't enough content to fill the screen?
2. The top Nav bar, what is the best way to make that collapse nicely when the screen size is reduced?
3. And finally, please feel free to critique my code, any tips, ticks or lessons would the appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

here is the code:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700,400|Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800);


body {
 font-size: 87.5%;
 font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.3;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
 margin: 0;
 border-bottom: solid black 2px;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
}

header {
 background-color: white;
 height: 200px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
 width: 30%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: rgb(105, 64, 16);
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.logo h1 {
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: white;
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
}

nav {
 width: 70%;
 background-color: rgb(50, 77, 105);
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 min-height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;

}
nav ul {
 width: 90%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 50px auto;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px;
 background-color: rgb(224, 204, 142);
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 }


nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 padding: 25px;
 margin: 0 12px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px;
 background-color: rgb(121, 207, 219);
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(17, 44, 96);


}

.content-wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 clear: both;
}

.home-content {
 width: 66%;
 padding: 20px;
}

.home-sidebar {
 width: 26%;
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
 background-color: rgb(50, 77, 105);
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

footer ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
 padding: 0;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: white;
 }

footer h1 {
 font-size: 30%;
 color: white;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" >

 <title>Test</title>
    </head>


<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<header>

        <div class="logo">
        <h1>Logo Goes Here</h1>
        </div>

        <nav>
        <ul>
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
        <li>Page 4</li>
        <li>Page 5</li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

</header>


<div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="home-sidebar">

        <h2>Sidebar info</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</P>


    </div>

    <div class="home-content">

        <h2>Welcome to company name</h2>

        <p>Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem.</p>

        <p>Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo.</p>

</div>

    </div>


<footer>

<ul id="footNav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Terms &amp; Conditions</li>
    <li>Privacy policy</li>
    <li>Copyright</li>
    <li>Disclaimer</li></ul>

    <h1 id="Copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016 Testing: Something &amp; Something. All Rights Reserved.
    </h1>


</footer>

</div>
</body>

<html/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- to make  your footer sticky you can use

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

2- you could learn how to make your website responsive via [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

3- your code is good as a beginner but you have to see a lot of websites already made to could produce something like it, you can learn a lot from [w3schools](http://w3schools.com)

Good luck!

Comment: w3schools has a lot of obsolete information and remind that it has nothing to do with the W3C . I would not recommend this site to a beginner :) who won't be abble to sort out the good things from the bad or obsolete practice ...

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks for your opinion but I think w3schools is a good resource when you are looking for a meaning of something, what is its syntax, when, how and why we should use it which is a very good resource for a beginner , I was completely depend on it 3 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use 
    `position : fixed
    bottom : 0
    width : 100%`
   css property to fix the footer at the bottom of the screen.
2. You can have a look at [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) to nicely hide your nav bar. Use [CSS Media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) Queries to get height of device
3. You have done good work so far, keep improving

Answer (score 0):

For the sticky footer use this code.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*container of the main section of the page*/ 
.content-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto
}
```